# how to do a specific action on multiple items from html table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am very new to PHP.
Also I am not so much trained in HTML.
However I am trying to open my self to this field.
My problem is that I filled an HTML table from a MYSQL database using PHP do while loop for some reason.
The table consists of 8 columns, the first on is a check box.
And just under the table there is a drop down list { input} with a button next to it.
I did this so I can do some updates to multiple rows in the database with on click rather than edit each item seperatley.
here is my code.

```
do {
    echo'<form name="multi_action" method="post" action="do_action.php" class="login">';
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check' value='check'";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['company_name'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['company_contact_person'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['company_address'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['company_phone'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['company_notes'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['company_email'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['company_statues'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
} while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc());
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($mysqli);
echo'<select name="to_do">
                            <option value="to_black_list" action="movetoblacklist.php">Move to Black List</option>
                            <option value="to_vip_list" action="movetoviplist.php">Move to VIP List</option>
                            <option value="remove" action="remove.php">Delete</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="button" name="apply" value="Apply"></input>
                        <div class="cleaner_h40"></div>
                        </form>';
```

don't even know where to start
any hint ?

Comment: Please use proper punctuation and capitalization in your questions.

Comment: just a little advice when coding php you can end the php tag whenever you like and then write your html whitout all the "echo" : 


`<?php do { ?> 
<table><tr><td></td> .... 
<?php }while(...) ?>`